# Save pixel data in txt format in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, getpixel

My program is to extract the pixel from an image and to save the pixel data in the text file for analysis. My picture is a binary image that gives only 255 and 0 's

**Here is the program:**

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("thresh.jpg")
pixel = im.load()
row, column = im.size
for y in range(column)
    for x in range(row)
        pixel = pix[x, y]
```

**Question:**

I want to save the `pixel` data in a text file. Suggest me some techniques to save the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a file writer object and write the value of the variable pixel to that.

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("thresh.jpg")
fil = open('file', 'w')
pixel = im.load()
row, column = im.size
for y in range(column):
    for x in range(row):
        pixel = pix[x, y]
        fil.write(str(pixel) + '\n')
fil.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am getting a `type error: expected a  character buffer object`

Comment: I am getting error like `type error: expected a character buffer object` for the line `file.write(pixel)`

Comment: Now i have to save the 'pixel' with its positions x and y for eg: x=100 y=100 pixel = 255.... how can i save using `file.write`

Comment: i got it `fil.write(str(x)+str(y)+str(pixel)+'\n')`

Comment: yep, x and y are integers. You can't do like int + str . It won't do the concatenation. For this, you need to type convert the x and y.

Comment: ya i gave like  `fil.write(int(x)+int(y)+str(pixel)+'\n')` it was not accepting integers it is accepting only `str(x)`